# Excel Formula COUNTIFS and counting non-blank cells

Tags: excel

I know this has been answered before, but I have tried the formulas suggested.

I am trying to count rows only if the first column has specific text (at least partial text) and the second column is NOT blank.

Here is my formula:

```
=SUM(SUMIF(A2:A33,"BA*",B2:B33)/SUM((COUNTIFS(A2:A33,"BA*",B2:B33,"<>"))*2))
```

[image: screenshot]

My problem is that the rows where Column B is blank are still getting counted.

I have tried:

```
=SUM(SUMIF(A2:A33,"BA*",B2:B33)/SUM((COUNTIFS(A2:A33,"BA*",B2:B33,"<>"&""))*2))
```

Same results.

Evaluation shows:

```
=SUM(8/SUM((COUNTIFS(A2:A33,"BA*",B2:B33,"<>"&""))*2))
THEN:
=SUM(8/SUM((7)*2))
THEN:
=SUM(8/14)
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you trying yo count or sum? and what exactly are you trying to count (expected output)?

Comment: The cells in column B can't be truly blank. Select the ones that look blank and press Delete - does the result change? (also, you don't need the two SUM functions)

Comment: You could create a new column, C, and fill it with a formula that is either 0 or 1 depending on whether or not you want to count the corresponding value in B. Then a sum of C could give you the sum you want. A bit of a kludge but perhaps useful (e.g. could be used with a sumproduct as well)

Comment: Rory wins the gold star!  I had a formula in column B, but when I copy and pasted only the VALUES into that column it didn't seem to be considered blank.  Odd.  Anyway, thanks for the suggestions!!

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A33,"BA*",B2:B33,"<>")
```